# Авторизация Вконтакте не работает

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

```
<?php
if($_GET['code']!=null)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['code']=$_GET['code'];
    header("Location: /vk.php");
    }
    session_start();
    ?>

    <a href="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3399327&scope=friends&redirect_uri=mk5tc.tk/vk.php&response_type=code">aaa</a>

    <?php
    $obj=json_decode(@file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=3399327&client_secret=_KEY_&code=".$_SESSION['code']."&redirect_uri=mk5tc.tk/vk.php"),true);
    echo("<br><br>".$obj['error'].":".$obj['error_description'].$obj['access_token']);
    echo("<br><br>code:".$_SESSION['code']);
    ?>
```

Вот, это мой код для авторизации Вконтакте, я запрашиваю ключ, гет запросом его мне возвращают.

Всё верно, ключ видно, всё работает.

После этого я делаю запрос с ключем(джейсон) с целью получить токен. В случае если токен есть выводится токен на экран, если его нет выводится сообщение об ошибке. У меня не разу за весь день не получилось подцепить токен.

Выдаёт следующее: invalid_grant:Code is invalid or expired.

Что делать подскажите.

Всё АПИ настроено, сайт зареган, секретный ключ получен.

Что не так? Не понимаю

Comment: Сервер-сервер запрос должен идти только после возврата кода от соцсети, то есть вместо вашего редиректа на vk.php.

Потому, что с валидным кодом, вы никогда не попадаете на access_token-запрос.

Comment: Ща попробую

Comment: invalid_grant:redirect_uri is invalid, please pass same redirect_uri, you used in authorize method.

Выдал вот это. Реализация ниже.

if($_GET['code']!=null)
{
$obj=json_decode(@file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=3399327&client_secret=qwertqwert&code=".$_GET['code']."&redirect_uri=mk5tc.tk/vk.php"),true);
}


+Убрал редирект

Comment: Пишу ответом, бо не влазит.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php

    $app_id = "*****";
    $app_secret = "******************";
    $my_url = "http://*****.com/oauth/vk.php";

    session_start();

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) 
   {
     $dialog_url = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id='.$app_id.'&scope=offline&redirect_uri='.$my_url.'&response_type=code';
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }
   else
   {
     $token_url =  'https://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$code.'';

     $params = json_decode(@file_get_contents($token_url));

     print_r($params);

     $graph_url = 'https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/getProfiles?uid='.$params->user_id.'&access_token='.$params->access_token.'&fields=photo,nickname';

     $user = json_decode(@file_get_contents($graph_url));
     $userResponse = $user->response[0];

     if ($userResponse->uid != '')
    {
          print_r($userResponse);
          echo ('Вы успешно авторизованны через вКонтакте');   
    }
    else echo('Ошибки авторизации!');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, буду от вашего ответа плясать, благодарю, добра Вам, пусть у Вас всё будет замечательно!

Comment: Ну вы это) Я ж всего лишь кусочек кода подсказал) Спасибо, конечно!

Comment: не работает, контакт отдаёт ошибку 404

Answer (score 1):

Не работает redirect_uri - который указываешь в приложении и в самом скрипте - адрес сайта - всё остаётся ответом на стороне вконтакте.