# Авторизация ВКонтакте Java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Нужен полноценный класс,который проводит авторизацию пользователя ВКонтакте и даёт токен для дальнейшего его использования.

Я читал документацию от API Вконтакте..

Читал Хабр...

Ничего годного не нашел.

Максимум к чему удалось прийти это к переходу на страницу с кодом,который нужно вырвать из адресной строки...
Пытался парсировать полученный сайт,код он мне не возвращал.

```
package vkmail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Authorize {

    //подключились к авторизации
    public void authorize() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=5890152&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/authorize&scope=messages&offline&response_type=code&v=5.62");

        url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        is.close();
        System.out.println(url.toString());



    }

}
```

Прошу вас не пишите мне ссылки на хабр и их темы про печатать посты на стену,как они делали авторизацию.Я читал всё это. Руки значит растут не из того места.
Просто помогите реализовать класс,подскажите,что нужно было делать для получения токена,какой ход действий.

Чтобы пользователю приходилось вручную копировать свой токен и вставлять - мне это не нужно.
Проще сделать автоматизацию.
Пропарсить ссылку с токеном.
Но я не понимаю.Потому нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: А что вам нужно-то сделать? Просто использовать `ACCESS_TOKEN` при вызове на сервере или делать авторизацию пользователей через OAuth?

Comment: авторизация OAuth. В дальнейшем я привяжу его к интерфейсу и оно будет вызываться по кнопке.

Comment: @EgorSmolyakov токен будет использоваться в коде программы в дальнейшем.

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно эту страницу - https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user

Comment: Проще всего токен 1 раз получить руками, в дальнейшем времени он не будет меняться

Comment: а вообще я посоветовал бы ознакомиться с тем как эту проблему уже решили на других языках, например php http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189304/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Malice то чувство,когда не шаришь в php и не хочешь на него тратить время,чтобы перевести код.

Comment: @Malice я тоже пришел к решению,что получить его руками лучше.
Посмотрим может кто-то даст годный ответ,прошу не минусовать тему.