# Не работает авторизация Вконтакте PHP API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию на PHP через api вконтакте. Вот код:

```
<?php

$app_id = "<app_id>";
$app_secret = "<app_secret>";
$my_url = "https://mysite.ru/testapi2/vk/";

session_start();

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code))
{
    $dialog_url = 'https://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='.$app_id.'&scope=offline&redirect_uri='.$my_url.'&response_type=code';
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
else
{
    $token_url =  'https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$code.'';
    echo $token_url;
    $params = json_decode(@file_get_contents($token_url));

    print_r($params);

    $graph_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/getProfiles?uid='.$params->user_id.'&access_token='.$params->access_token.'&fields=photo,nickname';

    $user = json_decode(@file_get_contents($graph_url));
    $userResponse = $user->response[0];

    if ($userResponse->uid != '')
    {
        print_r($userResponse);
        echo ('Вы успешно авторизованны через вКонтакте');
    }
    else echo('Ошибки авторизации!');
}

?>
```

Пример взят отсюда [Авторизация Вконтакте не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189304/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

Мне выдаёт сообщение "Ошибки авторизации!". Я решил в echo вывести полную ссылку

```
$token_url =  'https://api.vk.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$app_secret.'&code='.$code.'';
echo $token_url;.
```

Потом эту ссылку добавить в строку браузера и перешёл, чтобы проверить получу я токен или нет, в итоге вывело следующее сообщение

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code is invalid or expired."}.
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с [официальной документацией](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites), в которой указан пример вашей ошибки.

Comment: У меня всё получилось, только вот на одном сайте был пример где при получении user.get нужно было указывать uid, я посмотрел в интернете, что это такое оказывается это id пользователя, только вот идентификатор пользователя (если посмотреть через print_r выбранные данные user.get) автоматически добавляется без uid, а uid уже не отображается хоть я его тоже добавляю. Что-то я не пойму он уже не нужен?

Comment: дело в том, что параметр `uid` (тот же `user_ids`), не обязателен в том, случае, если передан `access_token` (при таком условии покажется информация о владельце токена).